# MAC OS Terminal Command Date

Tags: macos, terminal, operating-system

Help guys! How to display date and time in two separate strings in mac os terminal by one command ofc?

can not find anything

Comment: Did you try something like 

date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you may call the date command in one line two times. This is an easy solution. Commands are separated by ; so

```
date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d"; date "+TIME: %H:%M:%S"
```

would produce the strings:

```
DATE: 2023-02-22
TIME: 11:17:30
```

You may also pipe a one command result like above and separate the strings by a regex.